# Digit recognition with ocrmypdf

Tags: ocr, tesseract-ocr

I would like to get a "5" out of this image using ocrmypdf:

[image]

I tried:

```
ocrmypdf digit.png --output-type none --image-dpi 300 --sidecar side.txt - > /dev/null
```

But nothing, the sidecar is empty, and in stderr it prints that the file is empty.

I also tried to upscale the image with ImageMagick before passing it to ocrmypdf, still nothing.

Comment: Tesseract tells me that is a "d". Maybe check out preprocessing tricks like https://docparser.com/blog/improve-ocr-accuracy/

Comment: I used the second example here: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/tesseract-ocr-with-java-with-examples/ and it now correctly identifies it as a "5". I know its not the same lang but ocrmypdf also uses Tesseract under the hood.

Comment: Also, using a JPG is in my testing better than a PNG.